# Describe Interim Table and Basic Concept behind it?

Tags: sql-server

Hy Everyone...
Can anyone describe me what is interim table in sql Server 2008? what is the basic concept and structure behind it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the first result on Google... http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/04/sql-server-what-is-interim-table-simple-definition-of-interim-table/

Answer (score 1):

Interim table is a table that is generated by joining two tables and not the final result table. In other words, when two tables are joined they create an interim table as resultset but the resultset is not final yet.

[Check this link for examples](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/04/sql-server-what-is-interim-table-simple-definition-of-interim-table/)